# "nightwatchjs- cucumber" how to pass user name and password through command line?

Tags: cucumber, nightwatch.js

my Step definition looks like this

```
 When(/^I login $/, async () => {
     await login.waitForElementVisible('@form')
     login.setValue('@username', 'username')
     login.setValue('@password', 'password')
     login.click('@login')
 })
```

i need a way to pass my username and password though command line instead of passing them in code(for security purpose) is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 1):

You could set some `ENV` variables in your nightwatch.conf

```
"globals": {
  "username": process.env.ENV_USERNAME
}
```

and call it like so:

`$ ENV_USERNAME=john nightwatch ...`

But I would recommend using different environments within nightwatch.conf for every set of test data since this is the designated way to do this in nightwatch